# Form submission and mail send

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a form for registration by php .The form has submitter email address field.I want that after form submission , form content will send to both form submitter and admin via submitter email address and admin email address. Submitter email address will get from submitter email address field.Admin email address is fixed .
For Submitter
headers= "from : no-reply@eschool.com"
messagebody same as it is

For admin
headers=" from :$email"
messagebody same as it is

I tried to do this:

Html code:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" width="400" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="address" width="400" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" width="400" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <p><input type="text" name="pass" width="400" /></p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="insert" value="Insert" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**action.php**

```
$name    = $_POST["name"];
$address = $_POST["address"];
$email   = $_POST["email"];

$password = $_POST['pass'];
$subject  = "Thank you for your registration.";
$admin    = "info@editor.com";

$to = $email . "," . $admin;

$email_message .= "Name: ". $name."\n";
$email_message .= "Address: ".$address."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".$email."\n";
$email_message .= "password: ".$password."\n";

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8;" . "\n";
$headers .= "content-Transfer-encoding: 8bit" ."\n";
$headers .= "From: no-reply@eschool.com ". "\n";

mail($to, $subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfect, what is your are facing problem, plz write your problem.
Make following change in action.php for your convenience :

```
<?php
   $name    = $_POST["name"];
   $address = $_POST["address"];
   $email   = $_POST["email"];
   $password = $_POST['pass'];
   $subject  = "Thank you for your registration.";
   $admin    = "info@editor.com";
   //$to = $email  $admin;
   $email_message = '';

   $email_message .= "Name: ". $name."\n";

   $email_message .= "Address: ".$address."\n";

   $email_message .= "Email: ".$email."\n";

   $email_message .= "password: ".$password."\n";


   $headers1  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
   $headers1 .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";   
   $headers1 .= "From: no-reply@eschool.com ". "\n";

   $headers2  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
   $headers2 .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";   
   $headers2 .= "From: ". $email . "\n"; 

   if(@mail( $email, $subject, $email_message  , $headers1 )) {
     @mail( $admin, $subject, $email_message  , $headers2 )          
    echo "Mail Sent.";
   } else {
    echo "Mail Not Sent.";
   }
?>
```

Comment: The problem is: I want that if one submit form, then he/she will receive email from no-reply@eschool.com and admin will receive email from submitter email address.

Comment: My above code will work fine and resolve your problem. please vote of it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make two different versions of your headers and execute `mail(...)` twice:

```
<?php

    $name    = $_POST["name"];
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $email   = $_POST["email"];

    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $subject  = "Thank you for your registration.";
    $admin    = "info@editor.com";


    $email_message = "Name: ".$name."\n";
    $email_message .= "Address: ".$address."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".$email."\n";
    $email_message .= "password: ".$password."\n";

    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8;\n";
    $headers .= "content-Transfer-encoding: 8bit\n";

    $poster_headers = $headers . "From: no-reply@eschool.com\n";
    $admin_headers = $headers . "From: ".$email."\n";

    mail( $admin, $subject, $email_message, $admin_headers );
    mail( $email, $subject, $email_message, $poster_headers );
?>
```